# Equalizing Element Heights with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing Javascript that will take an element with the class of "eqlizm", get the .offsetHeight of all the .children, determine the max value, and then set the heights of all the .children to that value.

My problem is that while I can get it to echo the values out, it is only setting them for the first child.

I have the code setup on [CodePen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwEOgE) but here is the script, complete with my diagnostic console.logs:

```
var eqlizmContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".eqlizm");

function getArrMax(numArray) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}

function findMaxHeight(targetContainer) {
    var eqlizNodes = targetContainer.children;
    var childHeights = [];

    for (c = 0; c < eqlizNodes.length; c++) {
        childHeights.push(eqlizNodes[c].offsetHeight);
    }
    return getArrMax(childHeights);
}

function eqlizHeight(targetContainer) {
    var eqlizNodes = targetContainer.children;
    //console.log(eqlizNodes);

    for (c = 0; c < eqlizNodes.length; c++) {
        //console.log(targetContainer + " " + c);
        //console.log(eqlizNodes[c]);
        eqlizNodes[c].style.height = findMaxHeight(targetContainer) + "px";
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < eqlizmContainers.length; i++) {
    //console.log("Tier " + (i+1) + ": " + findMaxHeight(eqlizmContainers[i]) + "px");
    eqlizHeight(eqlizmContainers[i]);
}
```

After I get this function working, I will be adding event listeners for the resizing of the browser window.

I have looked high and low for a solution but all of the ones I could find involve jQuery which I want to avoid using that.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `.offsetHeight` rather than `.getBoundingClientRect().height`, also, is there a specific browser level you must target (say, IE6-8)?

Comment: I originally was trying .height and someone recommended .offsetHeight instead. I will look up .getBoundingClientRect(). IE 9 is the floor. I generally do not support IE8 and below.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem with the code you posted is that you're misunderstanding variable scoping in JavaScript.

All variables are function-scoped, regardless of the block in which they're initialized.

Your `c = 0` is being saved in the global scope.
`window.c; //0`
Thus, inside of `eqlizHeight`, you're setting `c` to 0, and then for each call to `findMaxHeight` (which looks like a pretty big de-op, that would be better suited to run outside of the loop, and be stored once per parent), you're running the value of `c` up to the length of the children of the first parent.

The quick and dirty solution is to add `var c = 0;` to your variable declarations in the functions.

Then your `for` constructs can look like `for (; c < ...; c++)`.

I prefer working in a functional fashion, without explicit looping, so I had a quick run at a second solution:

```
// turns an array-like into an array (el.children, document.querySelectorAll(...), etc)
function slice (arrlike, start, end) {
  return [].slice.call(arrlike, start, end);
}

// takes a property name and returns a reusable function
// var getName = pluck("name");
// getName({ name: "Bob" }); // Bob
// [{ name: "Bob" }, { name: "Doug" }].map(getName); // ["Bob", "Doug"]
function pluck (key) {
  // returns a function, which will pull the same property from any object it gets
  return function (obj) { return obj[key]; };
}

// it's just faster calling query(selector); than document.querySelector(selector);
function query (selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector);
}

// same as above, but I also turn the resulting HTMLCollection into an Array
function queryAll (selector) {
  return slice(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
}

// take an array of numbers and return the max
function max (numbers) {
  numbers = Array.isArray(numbers) ? numbers : slice(arguments);
  return Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);
}

// take an array of numbers and return the min
function min (numbers) {
  numbers = Array.isArray(numbers) ? numbers : slice(arguments);
  return Math.min.apply(Math, numbers);
}

// returns an object with top, right, bottom, left, width, height in pixels
// (measured from the visible part of the page, so scrolling affects the numbers)
function getBoundingClientRect (el) {
  return el.getBoundingClientRect();
}

// takes a style-name, and value, and returns a reusable function
// var setHeightTo100 = setStyle("height", "100px");
// setHeightTo100(el_1);
// setHeightTo100(el_2);
function setStyle (key, value) {
  // sets the same el.style[key] = value; for every element it's passed
  return function (el) { el.style[key] = value; };
}

// takes an array of elements
function resizeChildren (nodes) {
  nodes = Array.isArray(nodes) ? nodes : slice(arguments);
  // for each element ("container")
  nodes.forEach(function (container) {
    // get the container's children as an array
    var children = slice(container.children);
    // get the max( ) of the .height properties of the boundingClientRects of the children
    var maxHeight = max(children.map(getBoundingClientRect).map(pluck("height")));
    // set style.height = maxHeight + "px" on each child
    children.forEach(setStyle("height", maxHeight + "px"));
  });
}

// for a list of all ".eqlizm" children, resizeChildren
resizeChildren(queryAll(".eqlizm"));
```

If you paste that into your pen, I think you'll find that it works just fine.

### Edit: illustrating the quick & dirty fix to the preexisting code

```
var eqlizmContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".eqlizm");
var i = 0;

function getArrMax(numArray) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, numArray);
}

function findMaxHeight(targetContainer) {
    var eqlizNodes = targetContainer.children;
    var childHeights = [];
    var c = 0;

    for (c = 0; c < eqlizNodes.length; c++) {
        childHeights.push(eqlizNodes[c].offsetHeight);
    }
    return getArrMax(childHeights);
}

function eqlizHeight(targetContainer) {
    var eqlizNodes = targetContainer.children;
    var c = 0;

    for (c = 0; c < eqlizNodes.length; c++) {
        eqlizNodes[c].style.height = findMaxHeight(targetContainer) + "px";
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < eqlizmContainers.length; i++) {
    eqlizHeight(eqlizmContainers[i]);
}
```

Other than removing the comments, all I've done is added two `var c;` lines.
Whether you initialize `var c` to a value or not doesn't matter; all that matters is that you use `var` to announce it.
Otherwise, it gets saved in the global scope.

Sure, you could just keep using `a, b, d, e, f, g, h, j, ...`, but that means that any time two pieces of code on the same page use `x`, one will overwrite the other...

`var c;` inside of the function tells JavaScript that `c`'s home is there, and not to look any higher up.

Comment: It works, but I have to be honest: I don't know what half of that is doing.

Comment: @belinus  I’d suggest that most of it is worth learning. The `Array.isArray( )` stuff is just letting me pass in either an array of things, or passing in each item as a separate argument. You can ignore that and just assume that every function that has it is meant to work on arrays. Start from the `resizeChildren` function and work backwards. Like I said above, if you fix your `c`s, your original code should work. But in terms of reusability, and atomicity, learning slightly more functional approaches is very worth it.

Comment: Would using a different counter variable to replace the second 'c' work?

Comment: Sure, but by not declaring the variable, and rather setting another variable in the global scope, you're just going to have your app crash in even more ridiculous places, when you invariably have some other piece of code overwriting it.

Have a look at the update which I will shortly write, to my answer...

Answer (score -1):

Assign them all targets a similar class and loop through them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = 0;
    $(".homepage-product").each(function(){
        if ($(this).height() > height){
            height = $(this).height()
        }
    });

    $(".homepage-product").each(function(){
        $(this).height(height);

    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE example](https://jsfiddle.net/RichardJRVoice/neLpev81/12/)

Comment: That's jQuery. I want to avoid using that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have seen that you were asking specifically for JavaScript. Can I ask why you wish to avoid JQuery?

Comment: I don't want to be too dependent on it, plus I don't see the point of sending the user a 95k script library when what I am doing is about 2-3k of vanilla JS.